# IP changes network share problem

Tags: linux, networking, network-drive

Hii all,
         I was able to map a network drive(linux machine folder) on my windows box .but now ip of linux machine has changed and now when i tring to map the same drive again ,i could n't able to do so... could anyone tell me is it because of ip has changed and if it is so how do i tackle it??

Answer (score 2):

Use names (assigned by DHCP server) to mount network drives.

Before mounting again, try to go into any folders menu (on the top), then Connect a Network Disc and unmount current one (with old IP). This usually helps

Comment: Thanks Poltos could u plz explain it more means how use names assigned by DHCP server ,from where to get those names nd am trying to mount it from command line

Comment: @AMIT Your windows and linux needs to have IP addresses to communicate. There are two options for this: 1. use static IP. This is not your case, since you have experienced changes in IP. 2. you are getting these addresses from some DHCP. Usually machines requesting for an IP send their prefered "name" to the DHCP servier in hope that he also manages DNS records for the LAN. For example, this is the case if dnsmasq is used as DHCP server or Windows Server. Linux tries to get the name used as hostname, windows it's default machine name.

Comment: @AMIT Another option is to rely on SMB names: there are not DNS!! SMB protocol also sends broadcast frames over the network to inform neighbours about node names. Linux uses names described in /etc/smb.conf, Windows uses machine name.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to use static IP addresses, or have a DHCP server that supports dynamic dns. There's not really any way around this. And for your network drive, you will need to map a new drive on the windows machine from the new address.

Some routers also have a system to always hand out the same IP to a system based on advertised hostname, or MAC address, essentially giving you a static IP without the configuration on the host.